# Verify my evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Please verify my evaluation of:$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}} \ dx$$

I am very new to integration, like an absolute beginner, and I used a very flawed approach.

---

Ok, so apparently another question looks similar but evaluates $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}} \ dx$. Here I want to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}} \ dx$

---

Please rectify my result and working:

Consider:$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}} \ dx+\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}}}{\cos^2(\frac{1}{x^2})} \ dx$$

Differentiating gives:$$-2F'(x)=\dfrac{\cos^2(x)}{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}}+\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}}=\dfrac{1}{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}}$$

So,$$-2F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}{\dfrac{1}{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}}} \ dx$$

Which gives(limits: $0$ to $x$):$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x}}=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}} \ dx+\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}}}{\cos^2(\frac{1}{x^2})} \ dx$$

Upon replacing $x=-\infty$, We get:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}} \ dx+\int_{0}^{0}{\cos^2(\frac{1}{x^2})} \ dx$$

Therefore, $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\infty}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}-0}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}} \ dx$$

---

The actual value is close to $0.87$, while $\sqrt{2/\pi}=0.797\cdots$

What is my mistake?

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306011/integral-int-0-infty-sinx2-x2-dx

Comment: I think that if you aren't super familiar with integration, this problem might be a little bit out of reach. You can use integration by parts to simplify it to an expression that involves some normal terms and then a Fresnel integral (integral of cos(x^2)) but then you need complex analysis to actually evaluate that integral.

Comment: That would be the normal course of action. However I want to prove the Fresnel integral on my own :). Hence I used this stupid method.

Comment: It is interesting what you are doing, but consider easier cases. Fresnel reqs complex analysis, not something woah, but it does. If I were you, i'd first get familliar when I can diff integral , introduce a parameter and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, since the function inside the integral is non negative, the integral will converge if and only if it is bounded.

$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}} \ dx$ can be written as

$$\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}} + \int_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2}}$$
The first integral exists because the integrand is continuous, and the second one is bounded by
$$\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2} \leq \frac{1}{x^2}$$
So the initial must converge to a value.

Comment: Very nice. So the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos^2(x^2)/x^2 dx$$ must diverge since the addition of this integral and $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin^2(x^2)/x^2  dx$$ must equal $$\int_{0}^{\infty}1/x^2  dx$$ which diverges